# Incluir campos null en consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

affiliates_orders: id, order_date, payout_status, payout_method_id

payout_methods: id, name

Tengo dos ordenes:

```
affiliates_orders_id = 4
order_date = "2020-05-07"
payout_status = "UNPAID"
payout_method_id = null
```

Y...

```
affiliates_orders_id = 1
order_date = "2020-05-05"
payout_status = "PAID"
payout_method_id = 1
```

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
    $payouts = AffiliateOrder::select
        (
        'affiliates_orders.id as affiliates_orders_id',
        'affiliates_orders.order_date as order_date',
        'affiliates_orders.payout_status as payout_status',
        'payout_methods.name as payout_methods_name'
        )
        ->join('payout_methods', 'payout_methods.id', '=', 'affiliates_orders.payout_method_id')
        ->whereYear('order_date', Carbon::now()->year)
        ->whereMonth('order_date', Carbon::now()->month)
        ->where('affiliates_orders.affiliate_id', $affiliate->id)
        ->orderBy('order_date', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

Con la cual obtengo esto:

```
affiliates_orders_id = 1
order_date = "2020-05-05"
payout_status = "PAID"
payout_methods_name = "Bank Account"
```

Pero debido a que en la primera orden payout_method_id es null no la muestra, sino solo la que si tiene un valor en dicho atributo.

Ya he probado con whereNull y otras opciones pero quizás no lo estoy aplicando bien.

Como podria resolver esto amigos?

Comment: Cambia join por left join así: `leftJoin`

Comment: Muchas gracias, de verdad no sabia pues estoy comenzando en Laravel. Que gran ayuda de verdad!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mas que una duda de Laravel o Eloquent es una duda respecto al uso de los `JOIN`:

- Cuando haces uso del método `JOIN` es el equivalente de un `INNER JOIN` el cual solo te servirá para recuperar los valores que de la tabla de la izquierda existan o tengan al menos un registro asociado en la tabla de la derecha, omitiendo quienes no cumplan dicha condición.
- Mientras que si cambias por el método `leftJoin` el cual su equivalente es directamente `LEFT JOIN` le indicas que no solo recupere los valores de la tabla de la izquierda que existen o están relacionados con al menos un registro de la tabla de la derecha, sino que además te muestre los registros de la tabla de la izquierda que no tienen al menos un registro relacionado en la tabla de la derecha

Entonces queda:

```
->leftJoin('payout_methods', 'payout_methods.id', '=', 'affiliates_orders.payout_method_id')
```

Comment: Mejor explicación imposible... Sé que esto me servira de mucho más adelante! Gracias de nuevo

Comment: No te creas, aquí hay mucha gente con el conocimiento para explicar esto 1000 veces mejor, pero me alegro te ayudé.